# What is the average number of deaths per episode?

Tags: game-of-thrones

While watching *Game of Thrones* and seeing people being killed left and right, I began to wonder:

**Just how many people die per episode (not just major characters but the minor characters as well)?**

I'm just wondering about an average, but a list that mentions the number of deaths for *each* episode would be good too.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Digg has produced a montage showing every single death in *GoT.*

> The [body] count comes to an unbelievable 5,179 — or **over 172 deaths per
>   episode**.

This obviously factors in the 5000(ish) soldiers killed at the start of the Battle of King's Landing

[Vulture.com](http://www.vulture.com/2012/03/game-of-thrones-pie-charts.html) uses a different methodology to convey the level of death in each episode of the first season, counting only murders and personal kills occurring on-screen.

[image]

Comment: Which season is that chart at the bottom for?

Comment: @anthonygrist - Season one

Comment: Digg will have a nightmare if they try to do this for *The Watchers on the Wall*. It’s pretty hard to tell whether any given victim of a blow is killed by it, or just injured. We still don’t know whether Ser Alliser survived or not.

Answer (score 5):

There is an amazing bit of journalism done over at the [Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/graphics/entertainment/game-of-thrones/?utm_term=.36eb18d94f30&noredirect=on), and it has been updated as the seasons have gone on.

As of this time, the page is updated for all of Season 8, last updated May 21st.

6,887 Total Deaths across 73 episodes, for an average of 94.3 deaths per episode.

| Season | Deaths | Episodes | Deaths per Episode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 59 | 10 | 5.9 |
| 2 | 130 | 10 | 13.0 |
| 3 | 87 | 10 | 8.7 |
| 4 | 181 | 10 | 18.1 |
| 5 | 246 | 10 | 24.6 |
| 6 | 540 | 10 | 54.0 |
| 7 | 1096 | 7 | 156.6 |
| 8 | 4548 | 6 | 758 |
| Total | 6887 | 73 | 94.3 |

> Methodology
>
> A death is counted only if:
>
> - The character is killed on-screen.
> - The character dies off-screen, but the death is confirmed or assumed due to imminent death while on screen.
> - Only prominent off-screen deaths are listed. (Prominence is determined mainly by importance to the plot.)

Comment: Ought to be interesting to see how many deaths they count for S8E5 :(

Comment: I will update my answer when we actually get the counts for S8E5, but I wonder if I should update my table (for now) to show 3 episodes for S8

Comment: Washington Post article updated May 21st, results updated based on their data.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Too bad the WP's numbers seem laughably low for the last season. The entire wight army was only counted as 1200 kills, and apparently there were only ~900 kills during the destruction of KL. Ridiculous.

Comment: 130 deaths for Season 2 seems very low if you count the destruction of a large part of the fleet attacking King's landing in Episode 9...

Comment: Adding their methodology to the answer