# In which episode of Game of Thrones did some men of the Night's Watch attack Craster's Keep?

Tags: game-of-thrones, episode-identification

I believe I missed that episode or was confused how the baby and mother got away and why the original men of the Night's Watch party in the mountains did not return as was hinted in later episodes.

Comment: They are men of the Night's Watch, not night watchmen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an episode of Game of Thrones where nobody dies?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/58593/is-there-an-episode-of-game-of-thrones-where-nobody-dies)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it. S03E04.

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/58666/5520

> And Now His Watch Is Ended** 38:49 Karl spikes Craster up through the bottom of his head with a dagger