# Are there any death-free episodes of The Walking Dead?

Tags: the-walking-dead

... for the purpose of this question, death of a person (including conversion to a zombie) and destruction of a zombie (typically by severe damage to the brain) count as "death".

If additional clarification is needed, the following situations also count as "a death appearing in the episode":

- Clear offscreen sounds of death
- Death portrayed even in a flashback or flashforward

Edit:  if no,  I'd accept the episode with the fewest deaths

Comment: I won't be surprised if duplicate,  but I can't find it.

Comment: Interesting question.  I look forward to finding out the answer myself!

Comment: @ThePopMachine You might be thinking of this: [Is there an episode of Game of Thrones where nobody dies?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/58593/21267)

Comment: It certainly felt like that was the case for most of the episodes in the first few seasons, one of the reasons I stopped watching the show.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If killing zombies counts as "death", then no, there are no "death-free" episodes of *The Walking Dead*.  Here's a list of every episode as of the time of this writing.  I will list at least one death - human or zombie - for each episode, but I won't be listing EVERY death in each episode.

**The episode with the fewest deaths may be season 7's *New Best Friends*, with a body count of just one zombie, and no humans; *Hostiles and Calamities* in the same season, with only one human death; or *The Cell*, also in season 7, with one human death.  Season 5's *Slabtown* might come in second, with one human death and a few zombies destroyed.**

---

## Season 1:

**Days Gone Bye:**  The criminals Rick and Shane exchange gunfire with; several zombies.

**Guts:** Several zombies, including the one Rick and Glenn cut up to coat themselves with zombie goop.

**Tell it to the Frogs:**  Several zombies, including one Daryl kills as he makes his first onscreen appearance.

**Vatos:**  Amy, Ed, other unnamed survivors at the Quarry campsite;  many zombies, both in the camp and in Atlanta.

**Wildfire:**  Zombie-Amy; several zombies outside the CDC;  Jim is left for dead but dies off-screen and alone.

**TS-19:**  Dr. Edwin Jenner and Jacqui choose to die in the self-destruction of the CDC.

## Season 2:

**What Lies Ahead:**  Several zombies killed during the search for Sophia;  a deer (killed by the same bullet that wounds Carl).

**Bloodletting:**  Several zombies at the high school where Otis and Shane look for medical supplies.

**Save the Last One:**  Otis, devoured by zombies after Shane betrays him and shoots him in the leg; several zombies inside and outside the school.

**Cherokee Rose:**  Several zombies, including the infamous "well-walker" - a bloated and waterlogged zombie trapped in a well, who splits in half during an attempt to remove him.

**Chupacabra:**  Several zombies, including a few who attack Daryl after he hurts himself in a fall from his horse.

**Secrets:**  Several zombies, including one who attacks Maggie in a pharmacy, and a large number who attack Shane and Andrea in a neighborhood they are investigating.

**Pretty Much Dead Already:**  An entire barn full of zombies, including Herschel's zombie-family, and, most notably, zombie-Sophia.

**Nebraska:**  Dave and Tony, two unfriendly survivors who find Rick, Glenn, and Herschel in a bar, threaten them, and are killed by Rick.

**Triggerfinger:**  At least one man from Dave and Tony's group, who was wounded by Herschel and then eaten by zombies;  several zombies surrounding the bar.

**18 Miles Out:**  Many zombies who attack Rick, Shane, and Randall at the facility where Rick and Shane planned to leave Randall.

**Judge, Jury, Executioner:**  Dale, wounded by a zombie and then put out of his misery by Daryl;  at least one zombie, including the one who attacked Dale.

**Better Angels:**  Several zombies;  Randall (killed by Shane), Shane (killed by Rick), zombie-Randall (killed by Daryl), zombie Shane (killed by Carl).

**Beside the Dying Fire:**  Many, many zombies who attack the farm;  Jimmy and Patricia, both killed by zombies.

## Season 3:

**Seed:**  Many zombies, including a large number in and around the prison.

**Sick:**  Many zombies in the prison; the prisoner Tomas, killed by Rick after trying to get Rick killed.

**Walk With Me:**  Several military personnel killed in a helicopter crash, and one who survives the crash but is killed by the Governor;  the other members of the soldiers' unit, killed by the Governor;  some zombies, including Michonne's "pets".

**Killer Within:**  Many zombies who attack the prison;  Lori (who suffers complications during labor and is then shot in the head by Carl), T-Dog, eaten by zombies;  the prisoner Andrew, killed by the prisoner Oscar.

**Say the Word:**  Several zombies, including the one who ate Lori's corpse.

**Hounded:**  Zombies who approach the walls of Woodbury;  three men (Crowley, Gargulio, and Tim) sent by the Governor, under Merle's leadership, to find Michonne, and are killed by Michonne.

**When the Dead Come Knocking:**  Some zombies, including one who is thrown into the cell where Glenn is restrained;  a Woodbury resident who dies of natural causes under observation by Andrea and Milton, and is killed by Andrea after he reanimates as a zombie;  a crazed hermit in a cabin in which Rick, Michonne, Daryl, and Oscar take refuge, after Michonne impales him with her sword.

**Made to Suffer:**  Donna, a member of Tyreese's group, killed by Tyreese after being bitten.  A number of Woodbury residents killed in Rick's attack on the town;  Oscar, killed in the same attack.  Zombie-Penny, killed by Michonne.

**The Suicide King:**  A Woodbury resident who had been bitten during the attack, and is shot to death by the Governor; a few zombies.

**Home:**  A number of zombies attacking a stranded family on a bridge are killed by Daryl and Merle; more zombies are killed after being released in the prison yard by the Governor's men;  the prisoner Axel is shot to death by the Governor.

**I Ain't a Judas:**  Several zombies, including one Andrea turns into a "pet" like Michonne's, and a few killed by Tyreese.

**Clear:**  Several zombies outside Morgan's new home and in a nearby bar;  Michonne, Rick, and Carl see a man hiking down the highway, and later, find his backpack in a large pool of blood.

**Arrow on the Doorpost:**  A number of zombies are killed outside the mill where Rick and the Governor have their meeting.

**Prey:**  Andrea kills a number of zombies in her attempt to escape Woodbury and reach the prison, and she and the Governor kill more of them in an abandoned factory.  A pit full of walkers for use by the Governor is doused with gasoline and set ablaze, killing some of the zombies and leaving the others immobile.

**This Sorrowful Life:**  Michonne and Merle kill a number of zombies;  Merle then attracts a herd of zombies and leads them to the mill where the Governor and his men are waiting to meet with Rick;  the zombies kill some of the men, and Merle kills others, including Ben, a former member of Tyreese's group.  The Governor kills Merle;  Daryl later kills zombie-Merle and a few other zombies.

**Welcome to the Tombs:**   The Governor kills Milton;  Andrea kills zombie-Milton but is bitten in the process;  the Woodbury residents attack the prison but are repelled, and Carl kills a teenager attempting to surrender.  The Governor then executes almost all of the retreating Woodbury residents, including Allen (Ben's father, and a former member of Tyreese's group).  Finally, Michonne joins a dying Andrea in the prison at Woodbury, off-camera, and a gunshot rings out - Andrea is dead.

## Season 4:

**30 Days Without an Accident:**  Walkers are killed along the prison fences and during a scavenging trip to a nearby store.  Beth's boyfriend Zach is killed by zombies.  Rick meets a woman named Clara, who ultimately kills herself.  Patrick dies of an unknown illness in the prison showers.

**Infected:**  Zombie-Patrick attacks other prisoners, leading to a minor outbreak of walkers in the cell blocks.  Lizzie and Mika's father is among the bite victims, and Carol kills him.  The other zombies in the cell block are also killed.  Another prison inhabitant, Charlie, has died of the same illness as Patrick and reanimated;  he too is killed.  Karen and David are found to be infected, and are put in quarantine, but Tyreese later discovers that they have been killed.

**Isolation:**  Zombies are killed during a mission by Daryl, Tyreese, Michonne, and Bob to find medicine.

**Indifference:**  Rick and Carol kill zombies while scouting for supplies; they meet a couple, Sam and Ana;  Ana is killed by zombies off-screen.  More zombies are killed by the group searching for medicine at a veterinary hospital.

**Internment:**  More of the people infected with the mysterious disease die and become zombies, including Dr. Subramanian;  Rick and Carl kill many walkers in a herd that collapses the prison's fences.

**Live Bait:**  The Governor kills some zombies in a flashback, then takes shelter with a family.  The family patriarch dies and reanimates, and the Governor kills him.

**Dead Weight:**   The Governor reunites with Martinez and his new group;  on a scavenging mission, they see a camp filled with other survivors, but leave them alone.  Later, they return to find the camp ransacked and all but one of the survivors dead;  they kill the last survivor.  They kill some zombies, then the Governor kills Martinez and Pete.

**Too Far Gone:**  Meghan is killed by zombies, then shot by the governor.  The Governor kills Herschel, his men kill some prison inhabitants, the prison inhabitants kill many of the Governor's people, Daryl kills Mitch, Michonne mortally wounds the Governor, Lilly finishes the Governor off, Lizzie and Mika kill Alisha and another of the Governor's people.

**After:**  Michonne kills zombie-Herschel, and many other zombies.  Carl kills a few zombies.

**Inmates:**  Tyreese witnesses two men being killed by zombies. Tyreese and Carol kill zombies, as do Daryl and Beth, Maggie, Sasha, and Bob, and Glenn and Tara.

**Claimed:**  Glenn and Tara join Abe, Eugene, and Rosita, and kill a small herd of zombies.  Rick kills a "Claimer" named Lou.

**Still:**   Daryl and Beth kill zombies at a country club and a moonshiner's shack.

**Alone:**  Daryl and Beth kill zombies in the woods and at a funeral home;  Bob, Maggie, and Sasha kill a herd of zombies in the woods.

**The Grove:**  Carol and Tyreese kill zombies;  Lizzie kills Mika; Carol kills Lizzie.

**Us:**  The Claimers kill zombies;  the Claimers kill Len, one of their own.  Glenn and Tara kill zombies, then Maggie, Abe, Eugene, Sasha, Bob, and Rosita kill a herd.

**A:**  Rick, Michonne, and Carl witness a man being killed by zombies.  Rick, Daryl, and Michonne kill the remaining Claimers including Joe and Dan, and another unnamed man.  After reaching Terminus, Rick uses a Terminite named Alex as a human shield, killing him.

## Season 5:

**No Sanctuary:**  The Terminites slaughter four people, including Sam from season four.  Carol attacks Terminus single-handed, wounding Mary and leaving her to be eaten by zombies, while Rick and the others kill many more Terminites.

**Strangers:**  Zombies near Gabriel's church are killed.

**Four Walls and a Roof:**  The remaining Terminites are killed:  Albert and Mike are shot to death, and Gareth, Martin, Theresa, and Greg are beaten and hacked to pieces.  Bob dies from a zombie bite he had suffered the previous day, unbeknownst to the group.

**Slabtown:**  A patient at Grady Memorial, named Gavin, dies. A few zombies outside the hospital are killed.

**Self Help:**  Abe, Rosita, Eugene, Glenn, Maggie, and Tara kill many zombies - some with a water cannon.  In a flashback, Abe kills a man with a can of food, then finds his wife and children dead.

**Consumed:**  Carol and Daryl kill zombies in Atlanta, and other zombies fall to their deaths from a bridge.

**Crossed:**  A number of zombies are killed, both in Atlanta during the mission to rescue Beth, and on the road, by Abe's group.

**Coda:**  Rick kills Lamson, one of Dawn's men from Grady Memorial.  Beth pushes another of the Grady men - O'Donnell - to his death in an elevator shaft.  Beth stabs Dawn, Dawn kills Beth, and Daryl kills Dawn.  A herd of zombies are crushed by a fire truck.

**What Happened and What's Going On:**  A number of zombies are killed in Noah's former neighborhood.  Tyreese is bitten, and soon dies.

**Them:**  Many zombies are killed, first on the road, then by a tornado outside the barn where the group is taking shelter.  A pack of feral dogs attacks the group, who kill and eat the dogs.

**The Distance:**  Many zombies are killed by the group, who have been joined by Aaron.

**Remember:**  A number of zombies are killed outside the walls of Alexandria, including one that had been left tied to a tree by Nicholas and Aiden.

**Forget:**  Carol kills a walker with "W" carved into its head; Aaron and Daryl kill a group of walkers that attacked a horse they were trying to catch;  Aaron kills the wounded horse.

**Spend:**  On a supply run, Aiden inadvertently kills himself by shooting a grenade on a zombie's chest;  Nicholas panics and gets Noah killed by walkers while he, Noah, and Glenn are trapped inside a revolving door. A construction team, including Abe, kills a herd of zombies that attacks them.

**Try:**   Sasha, Rosita, and Michonne dispatch a herd of zombies.  Daryl and Aaron find a dead woman with a "W" on her forehead tied to a tree; she reanimates and they kill her.

**Conquer:**  Daryl and Aaron follow a man in a red poncho, but fall into a trap and are forced to shelter in a car, which is quickly surrounded by zombies.  Morgan arrives, creates a gap, and the three men kill many of the walkers, then escape.   The Wolves catch the man in the poncho, slit his throat, and leave him for the zombies.  Glenn and Nicholas fight, killing zombies along the way.  Gabriel finds a wounded man being eaten by a zombie, and kills both of them. Rick kills a zombie that managed to slip into Alexandria.  Pete accidentally kills Deanna's husband, Reg.  Rick kills Pete.

## Season 6:

**First Time Again:**  While trying to clear a massive herd of zombies in a nearby quarry, Rick, his group, and some Alexandrians kill many walkers.

**JSS:**  Enid's parents are killed by walkers in a flashback.  The Wolves attack Alexandria, killing many of its inhabitants, including Holly;  Carol kills many Wolves, and a few other Alexandrians take out some attackers as well.

**Thank You:**  Many Alexandrians, including Annie, David, Sturgess, Barnes, and Nicholas, are killed by zombies (Barnes is actually *bitten* by a zombie, but *killed* by Michonne).  Rick is ambushed by five Wolves, and kills them all.

**Here's Not Here:**   Morgan is pursued by two men, whom he kills.  He meets Eastman, who is later bitten by a zombie and dies.  Eastman's goat, Tabitha, is killed by zombies.  Eastman and Morgan kill many zombies.

**Now:**  David's widow has committed suicide off-camera, and is now a zombie;  Jessie kills her.  Maggie and Aaron kill a few zombies in a sewer.

**Always Accountable:**  Sasha, Abe, and Daryl are ambushed, but kill their attackers.  Daryl meets Dwight, Tina, and Sherry; they, and men pursuing Dwight, Tina, and Sherry, kill zombies.  Tina is bitten by a zombie and dies.  Abe kills a zombie carrying a rocket launcher.

**Heads Up:**  We see Nicholas' death again.  Glenn kills zombie-David. Some of the walkers in the herd outside Alexandria's walls are killed when Spencer falls into their midst.

**Start to Finish:**  Rick kills two walkers in order to camouflage himself and a group of others.  Deanna, who has been bitten, kills some walkers before being killed off-screen.

**No Way Out:**  Daryl stabs one Savior to death, then uses the rocket launcher to kill 6 others.  Sam and Jessie are eaten by a herd, and Michonne stabs Ron to death when he tries to shoot Rick.  Carol shoots a Wolf, who is then eaten by zombies;  later, Morgan kills the zombie-Wolf.  The Alexandrians, led by Rick, take on a huge herd in hand to hand combat, killing all the zombies.

**The Next World:** Rick, Daryl, and Jesus kill walkers.  Spencer kills zombie-Deanna.

**Knots Untie:**  Rick, Abe, Glenn, Maggie, Jesus, and others kill zombies and rescue some of Jesus' friends.  At the Hilltop, Ethan tries to assassinate Gregory, but Rick kills him.

**Not Tomorrow Yet:**  Rick and a team of Alexandrians kill many zombies, then attack a Saviors outpost and kills dozens of people inside.

**The Same Boat:**  Taken prisoner with Maggie, Carol kills two of her captors.  A third dies of a gunshot wound inflicted by Carol earlier.  Five Saviors come to investigate, and Carol burns them alive.  Rick kills a captive Savior.

**Twice as Far:**  Several zombies are killed.  Saviors kill Denise;  Daryl, Rosita, and Abe kill several Saviors.

**East:**  Carol kills five Saviors.

**Last Day on Earth:**  The Saviors beat a man, then hang him from a bridge. Morgan shoots a Savior to death.   A few zombies are killed.

## Season 7:

**The Day Will Come When You Won't Be:**  Negan kills Abe and Glenn.  Rick kills zombies.

**The Well:**  Kingdom soldiers kill some zombies, some of whom they then feed to a herd of pigs.

**The Cell:**  Dwight kills a runaway Savior named Gordon.

**Service:**  Negan kills a zombie at the gate of Alexandria;  Michonne shoots other zombies, then a deer.

**Go Getters:**  Carl runs over a zombie;  Sasha, Jesus, and Maggie kill a herd at the Hilltop.

**Swear:**  Tara and Heath kill zombies before being separated.

**Sing Me a Song:**  Carl kills two or three Saviors.  Rick and Aaron kill zombies.

**Hearts Still Beating:**  Rick and Aaron kill zombies.  Daryl kills Fat Joey.  Michonne kills a female Savior off-camera.  Negan kills Spencer.  Arat, a Savior, kills Olivia.

**Rock in the Road:**  Rick and Michonne use a steel cable stretched between two cars to clothesline a massive herd of zombies.

**New Best Friends:**  Rick kills a heavily armored zombie.

**Hostiles and Calamities:**  Negan shoves Dr. Emmett Carson into a furnace, killing him.

**Say Yes:**  Rick and Michonne kill a ton of zombies.

**Bury Me Here:**  Two residents of the Kingdom die, as well as some zombies.

**The Other Side:**  One Savior and a few zombies are killed.

Comment: Well done, Chad! Maybe highlight the note about the episode with one zombie death only, as that episode wins the consolation prize.

Comment: Accepting as the right answer, so hopefully you will get the bounty posted by @Lan, or, I believe half of it if that user doesn't grant it.

Comment: "Rick kills heavily armored zombie". Plague must have hit during a LARP session. How did the zombie end up armored?

Comment: @Withywindle to make it sound even more comical, it is SPIKED armor. http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Winslow_(TV_Series)

Comment: Fantastic job! One more terrific answer! +110 from me

Comment: I really just want to see what snarky remark Chris Hardwick will make during an empty "In Memoriam" segment on *The Talking Dead*.

Comment: PS, that is my rapper name:  Snarky Remark